# INSERT INTO audit table when SELECT from table

Tags: sql, oracle

Is that applicable to use INSERT inside SELECT statement, in order to insert some data whenever we select. the scenarion is i need to audit the select operations so whenever we run SELECT statemnt we need to insert into a nother table, i have all the code for the select operation all what i need is to find a way to add INSERT statement inside SELECT statement

EX

```
SELECT *, (
    INSERT INTO auditTable(ID, CREATEDINFO) VALUES ( :v0, :v1)
) FROM mainTable;
```

Comment: did you tried insert into select ? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Have you looked into the built-in auditing tools? (e.g. [for 12cR2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html))?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, there may be better ways to do what you are asking, but for the example you have shown, you want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO auditTable(ID, CREATEDINFO)
  SELECT *
  FROM mainTable;
```

Note: I'm assuming there are only two rows in `mainTable` as your query suggests, otherwise you should specify which rows you are selecting rather than using `*`